# Drupal 7 - Views, loaded by Ajax

Tags: ajax, drupal, view, drupal-taxonomy

Two years ago I made a website to learn Flash, but these days Flash is loosing it's popularity. (the website never went online, was just for testing) Now I want to try making this test website with Drupal + Ajax...

[Take a look at the Flash website](http://www.svlhandbags.com/flash/)

I have a collection of handbags, with different types and sizes. So I use taxonomy for that. (content type: handbag, with taxonomy terms "type" and "size" - small, medium and large)

The visitor should choose a type in the navigation. (Silver Medallion or Silver Jewel) Then he sees a page (made with views) that shows all available sizes. (The type 'Jewel' doesn't have sizes, so this type should show all bags.)

After the visitor clicks a size, he sees all available items of that type and size. With views, this is quite simple... But now I want to do this with Ajax, so the page doesn't have to reload... I also want the path to change, so people can add a page to the favortites.

I found an answer that helped me a bit further, but I have no idea where to put the code...

[Code that helped me out... a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4966739/1099506)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a custom module to create the view and add the configuration in setting file, then create a js file and add to drupal project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. It seems to provide what you want: http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs/